# Stop Chrome from being a resource hog on Mac

Tags: google-chrome

How can on stop Chrome from being a resource hog on Mac. If it often opens up many Chrome helper task and I understand it should make my browser faster, but it's make my computer slower.

Comment: Maybe try: [The Great Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg) and/or a mac app: [App Tamer](http://www.stclairsoft.com/AppTamer/).

Answer (score 1):

Every page, every tab, needs its own helper task.

The only way to prevent it using resources is to limit the number of pages you have open at any given time.